# How to drop the virtual keyboard after keydown event on pressing enter in textbox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

```
private void tbox_KeyDown_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        //do something

}
```

What I want is that after the above keydownevent in textbox named tbox. I want the virtual keyboard visible on the phone screen to drop off, when I click Enter button. How could this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to set the focus to the page not the textbox.

```
private void tbox_KeyDown_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        this.Focus();
    }
}
```

Source:
http://www.jstawski.com/archive/2011/02/16/programmatically-hiding-the-keyboard-in-windows-phone-7-wp7.aspx